# Changing IPB Forum Layout

Tags: layout, forum, skin, ipb

It's very simple, but I haven't found the right file in the backend template editor.

I want to change this:
[image]

to this: [image]

I already have the very simple HTML setup, but I don't know where to put it.

Thanks in advance, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

globaltemplate is the file that you need.

This controls all the header & footer regions on every page.

Look & Feel -> manage skin sets & templates

Answer (score 0):

Look & Feel > Manage Skin Sets & Templates > YourTemplate

HTML code: globalTemplate

CSS: ipb_styles.css

You can also use Look & Feel > Search and Replace and enter a part of the code, such as a div class/id in order to identify the correct template file.

Bear in mind that you'd best search with single quotes if you don't find which template part you're looking for, i.e:

```
 <div id="test"> might be <div id='test'> inside the template files.
```